# Adobe Flash NOT Working on full screen

Tags: nvidia, 64-bit, flash, fullscreen, hp-pavilion

When I play flash videos in Firefox or Chrome and try to view it in fullscreen mode, it stops every second, the sound is good but not the video.

I think I have tried everything and nothing works, I;m driving me crazy with this bug

1. I already modified `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` assing line `"OverrideGPUValidation = 1" | sudo tee -a`
2. I checked the Sync to Vblank box in NVidia Settings
3. I unchecked the hardware acceleration in flash setting also re-activated it
4. Uninstalled Flash plugin and Installed Gnash, It did not worked
5. I already tried installing Flash-Aid in firefox, and it neither work

I have a 64 bits HP Pavillion with a GeForce 6150SE nForce 430/PCI/SSE2 as Graphic Card,

Comment: Flash has always been a major pain for Ubuntu. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Few days back i faced a similar issue.           I resolved this problem after removing the flash player and then manually installed flash back by downloading the flash from the Adobe's site and installing it via Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed it, I used to have installed the Nvidia drivers (current version), but I chaged it to version 96, through the additional drivers option, and now everything is working fine, version 173 did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a laptop AND you have a third party graphics card (i.e. better than the motherboard standard from Intel or others) then DISABLE the motherboard default option in the DEVICE MANAGER so that the ONLY operating option is the alternate NVIDIA or AMD option.